# Easybitcoin not working

Tags: bitcoin-core, php

I am new to this bitcoin world, I have installed bitcoin core on my centos server.
Bitcoin daemon is running fine. And commands like getinfo works fine on bitcoin-core.cli. But the same command getinfo does not work with easybitcoin.
My bitcoin.conf file looks like:

prune=4096
txindex=0
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=password
rpcport=8332
server=1

[image]

Inshort, commands are working with cli but not with easybitcoin. Please help.

Comment: What is "easybitcoin"? Why do you think it would respond to the same commandline interface as Bitcoind. Are you sure that you didn't download some malware?

Comment: https://github.com/aceat64/EasyBitcoin-PHP
A library based on curl to use bitcoin core functions

Answer (score 1):

If I had to venture a guess, I would say it's because [EasyBitcoin-PHP](https://github.com/aceat64/EasyBitcoin-PHP) hasn't been updated since June 2017, and the author actually states in the "About":

> A simple class for making calls to Bitcoin's API using PHP. This is an old library, I suggest instead using https://github.com/denpamusic/php-bitcoinrpc

Comment: I used the php-bitcoinrpc but still no luck. Not working for me. 
I am not even getting any error. What it could be ? Please help

Comment: This is the version info:
Bitcoin Core RPC client version v22.0.0